# How to split a Jupyter notebook into several slides?

Tags: jupyter, rise

Jupyter allows to produce slides either via `nbconvert` or (even better) dynamically and within a notebook with [RISE](https://damianavila.github.io/RISE/).

However, when I launch RISE on my notebook or create slides with `nbconvert`, it creates only a single (potentially huge) slide. I thought it would/could automatically split at every header lines, but it does not.

How can I split the notebook into different slides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bring in a specific tool that is not shown by default. In the notebook, go to

```
View > Cell Toolbar > Slideshow
```

and a drop-down menu now appears at the right end of each cell, showing a "slide label" (my terminology).

By default, the label is `-`, meaning that the cell is part of the same block than the cell above.

If you change the label to `slide`, the cell is now the first cell of a new slide. (`new slide` would probably be a better label indeed).

You will find other labels too that closely follow Reveal.js' way of working:

The `subslide` label correspond also to a new slide, but placed in a "vertical stack" so dear to Reveal.js. `fragments` are used for progressive display of the elements of a slide. `skip` cells are not displayed, and `notes` are for speaker notes.